# Could you survive on hydrox in at 10 atmospheres?

Tags: pressure, physical-chemistry, hydrogen, gas, combustion

I was told that hydrox is incredibly dangerous, that pure oxygen will combust without any source of ignition at 3 to 4 atmospheres of pressure, and that because humans are hydrocarbons they will act as fuel for the fire. I was also told that hydrogen, with even a trace of oxygen, will combust if there is any heat source. While I'm under the impression there's some truth to this, it seemed highly exaggerated.

So, I wanted to ask: If you were in a room with hydrox (something like 96% hydrogen and 4% oxygen), at 10 atmospheres of pressure, would you be safe? Would it "spontaneously combust"? Would you be terrified the, "slightest heat-source" would set off the oxygen or the hydrogen?

From what I looked up, hydrox is meant to be safe for about 500 to 700 meters of depth underwater, which is something like 50 to 70 atmospheres, if I'm not mistaken, so I hadn't assumed it to be so deadly dangerous as I was told it was.

Answer (score 1):

To use Hydrox, you need to ensure there is no possibility of a spark to ignite it. Hence, the safest place to use it is underwater. There is no "spontaneous combustion", a spark is required.

Hydrox, with the 96/4 ratio you mention, is used  in scuba gear for very deep dives. At high pressures, Nitrogen cannot be used as it causes Nitrogen narcosis.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrox_%28breathing_gas%29), the deepest dive recorded so far is to 160 m; however, in 1990, a simulated dive (in a hyperbaric chamber) to 701 m was made in France.

However, because of the dangers of Hydrox, Heliox (He/O), or [Trimix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimix_(breathing_gas)) (He/N/O) are normally used instead of Nitrogen for deep diving. The record using Heliox is 212 m.